# link for popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a user control that i want to build on. right now it just displays a dynamic number. i want to include functionality that will convert the number into a hyperlink that opens a popup window.

label in ascx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_num" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript or set the target to _new within the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may use the `Hyperlink` element instead of `Label`. You should add the `Target` attribute:

```
<asp:Hyperlink id="numScore" Target="_new"></asp:Hyperlink>
```

Anytime, you can change it's value with C#:

```
numScore.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: this put me on the right track but i also had to embed javascript in order to get a small popup window.

Comment: Yeah, but you can generate this javascript thing with C#